# Compare array of objects and return index of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got this array of objects:

```
[
{x: 615, y: 293, a: 1},
{x: 340, y: 439, a: 0},
{x: 292, y: 505, a: 0}
]
```

Basically im trying to write a collider. I'd love to return indexes of objects that values of x and y that are equal to each other, how do i approach this?

Comment: Values of x and y within each object or across the entire group of objects?

Comment: Short of implementing a KD-Tree, the simplest approach is a nested loop

Comment: across the entire group of objects

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that iterates, via map, through the array and returns the index or a null depending on this condition (x === y) and than filter it, returning only those that are different from null

```
const collider = array => 
   array.map( (item, index) => item.x === item.y ? index : null )
        .filter( item => item !== null)
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c3qqmh3b/

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding that's not exactly what i meant,
i'd need to know index of object that its X and Y is the equal to another object X and Y

Answer (score 0):

```
var indexes = myArray.reduce((idxs, el, i) => {
  if (el.x === el.y) {
    return idxs.concat(i);
  } else {
    return idxs;
  }
}, []);
```

If your `myArray` would be, for example:

```
myArray = [
  {x: 615, y: 293, a: 1},
  {x: 340, y: 340, a: 0},
  {x: 292, y: 505, a: 0}
]
```

then you'll get `[1]` as a result (because element of index `1` has `x===y`)

Comment: Better impl as mine (with map & filter), as long as it iterates only one time :-)

Comment: Can't see how running two simple functions is better than running one simple function. I guess It's more about if someone is familiar with `reduce` or not.

Comment: I have said that your implementation is better, because it's simpler to read one interaction ;)

Comment: Oh thanks then. Sorry, I misunderstood you :) Guess it would be easier if there would be 'then' instead of 'as' in your comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a hashtable to check for duplicates:

```
const hash = {};

for(const {x, y} of array) {
  if(hash[x + "|" + y]) 
    alert("collides");
  hash[x + "|" + y] = true;
}
```